# JQuery/Ajax POST call + download

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, post

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but I spent the last few hours reading through related questions and still got no working solution. I have a form that calls a POST method using Ajax, which returns a pdf file.

```
$("form#myForm").submit(function(){
var fileRequest = { data0: "test", data1: true };
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
formData.append('request', JSON.stringify(fileRequest));
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/my/method',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {

    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
});

return false;
});
```

Now, I have already learned that Ajax cannot handle file downloads, but I am wondering how else I should make a download window appear.

This is my servlet method:

```
@Path("/method")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response consumeFile(@DefaultValue("true") @FormDataParam("enabled") boolean enabled,
        @FormDataParam("request") FormDataBodyPart bean,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart file,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {

    file.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    bean.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    MyClass mc = bean.getValueAs(MyClass.class);
    InputStream in = file.getValueAs(InputStream.class);
    File pdfToReturn = process(in, mc);
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) pdfToReturn);
    response.header("Content Disposition","attachment;filename="+mc.getFileName());

    return response.build();
}
```

What is the correct way to download the returned file?

Comment: Did you test my answer or found another solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I show you how i solved this problem:

#### 1 Wrap your file as byte[] in a model class

```
public class FileModel {

  private String name;
  private String mimeType;
  private byte[] content;

  public FileModel(String name, String mimeType, byte[] content) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setMimeType(mimeType);
    this.setContent(content);
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getMimeType() {
    return mimeType;
  }

  public void setMimeType(String mimeType) {
    this.mimeType = mimeType;
  }

  public byte[] getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  public void setContent(byte[] content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

}
```

#### 2 Return the FileModel in your controller

```
@RequestMapping
  public @ResponseBody FileModel function() throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = serviceToGetTheFile.getFile();
    return new FileModel("Filename", "application/pdf", bytes);
}
```

#### 3 Get the file out of the response

```
...
success: function (response, status, xhr) {
    var fileModel = response.data;
    var blob = base64toBlob(fileModel.content, fileModel.mimeType);
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
...

function base64toBlob(base64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

  var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
  var byteArrays = [];

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {
    type : contentType
  });
  return blob;
}
```

At the end you have an url to load the pdf. If you like, you can create a new a-link with the url in href. Then click the link via javascript.

I hope I could help you!